# How to connect LOLIN 7 WS2812B LED's to Raspberry Pi Pico (RP2040)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, led, micropython, neopixel, raspberry-pi-pico

I have spent numerous hours googling for the solution, but no tutorial or guide uses the LED's that I own. Everyone keeps mentioning Data IN, and Data OUT, but there are no such markings on my LED's.

I only know that I need to connect the `5V` on LED with `VBUS` (`Pin 40`) Pin on Pi Pico, and `GND` on LED with `GND` (`Pin 38`) on Pi Pico.
Can someone please help me out?

I have following LED:
[image: LOLIN 7 WS2812B LED front side]

[image: LOLIN 7 WS2812B LED back side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of hardware was probably meant to be used with Wemos D1 Mini board, but you can use it with pico too. Connect D4 pin to any gpio on your pico, ground to ground and 5V to VBUS as you said. That's probably everything you have to connect. Than install Neopixel library and get the code from this link:

https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-pico-circuitpython/neopixel-leds

I don't this hardware at home, so I am not sure, but hope I at least showed you a way.

also pretty useful:
https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1_mini_shield/rgb_led.html